# How can I get more detail on why this REST service request is not working?

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010, rest, httpclient

My goal was to create a REST service that will allow me to POST and GET images.  I've got the GET portion working, however I'm having difficulty posting an image to the service I created.  Using the [WCF REST Service Template 40 (CS)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) template I created the following method to handle my POST.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "upload/?fileName={fileName}")]
public void AddImageToStore(Stream file, string fileName)
{
// Implementation goes here.  For now method is empty.
}
```

Below is the code I'm using to consume the above method.  If I uncomment line 3 and send nothing in the body everything works.  If I uncomment line 4 and send text in the body no error.  However, if I send the image in a stream I receive an error "BadRequest (400) is not one of the following: OK (200)..."

```
Stream theStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test.jpg"));
Uri uri = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:50001/MediaService/upload/?fileName=test.jpg");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(uri);
// HttpContent content = HttpContent.CreateEmpty(); //Status successful
// HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create("test", Encoding.UTF8); //Status successful
// HttpContent content = HttpContent.Create(theStream, "image/jpeg", theStream.Length); //Error when I send a stream!

HttpResponseMessage response = client.Post(uri, content);
response.EnsureStatusIsSuccessful();
```

This is my first attempt at consuming a REST service.  I'm stuck at the moment at how to debug this.  How can I get more detail on what the real error is?  The "BadRequest (400)..." error message is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error I was able to answer my own question.

It turns out I was sending files larger than the default buffer pool would accept.  I ended up tweaking the default values in my web.config for **MaxBufferPoolSize**, **MaxBufferSize**, and **MaxReceivedMessageSize**